# how to trigger cloud queue from smapi server?

Tags: sonos

Trying to configure a music service on Sonos.  I have been Following the Sonos guide for programmed radio.

https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-programmed-radio/

But not sure what should be returned from the smapi server to have the player use the endpoints declared in the manifest.

That would be step three in this graphic.

https://developer-assets.ws.sonos.com/doc-assets/prog_radio_seq10_review.png

I've tried adding radio as an itemType  and using some of the existing types    but so far I never got the player to make any requests to the cloud queue server.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:getMetadataResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <ns2:getMetadataResult>
                <ns2:index>0</ns2:index>
                <ns2:count>2</ns2:count>
                <ns2:total>2</ns2:total>
                <ns2:mediaCollection>
                    <ns2:id>smapicontainer:31</ns2:id>
                    <ns2:itemType>radio</ns2:itemType>
                    <ns2:title>radio collection</ns2:title>
                </ns2:mediaCollection>
                <ns2:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns2:id>smapicontainer:32</ns2:id>
                    <ns2:itemType>radio</ns2:itemType>
                    <ns2:title>radio metadata</ns2:title>
                </ns2:mediaMetadata>
            </ns2:getMetadataResult>
        </ns2:getMetadataResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

expecting to see some calls to the endpoint for radio type.  That are declared in the manifest. The manifest seems to be configured correctly as it does get calls  to  /radio/timePlayed   when playing sample tracks.

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.0",
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "uri": "https://13467fb8.ngrok.io/flight/radio"
    },{
      "type": "reporting",
      "uri": "https://13467fb8.ngrok.io/flight/radio"
    }
  ],
  "presentationMap": {
    "uri": "https://13467fb8.ngrok.io/flight/assets/presentationmap.xml",
    "version": 2
  },
  "strings": {
    "uri": "https://13467fb8.ngrok.io/flight/assets/strings.xml",
    "version": 2
  }
}
```

updated smapi response with mediaMetaData with itemType program.  Seems to be missing something still,  as the manifest "radio" endpoint does prevent calls to the smapi server.  But it still doesn't make any requests to the endpoint associated with radio.  I get "unable to play selected item"  alerts when the items are selected.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:getMetadataResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
            <ns2:getMetadataResult>
                <ns2:index>0</ns2:index>
                <ns2:count>3</ns2:count>
                <ns2:total>3</ns2:total>
                <ns2:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns2:id>prad:32</ns2:id>
                    <ns2:itemType>program</ns2:itemType>
                    <ns2:title>radio channel a</ns2:title>
                </ns2:mediaMetadata>
                <ns2:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns2:id>smapicontainer:33</ns2:id>
                    <ns2:itemType>program</ns2:itemType>
                    <ns2:title>radio channel b</ns2:title>
                </ns2:mediaMetadata>
                <ns2:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns2:id>radio:34</ns2:id>
                    <ns2:itemType>program</ns2:itemType>
                    <ns2:title>radio channel c</ns2:title>
                </ns2:mediaMetadata>
            </ns2:getMetadataResult>
        </ns2:getMetadataResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Below is the only traffic I can generate to the endpoints in the manifest file.
Nothing for type radio,  but do get some for reporting if I play one of the sample tracks included in the smapi sample server.
[image of traffic to the endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soqyq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the version number somewhere in the radio and reporting endpoints. See [Sonos Music API service reporting and manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596739/sonos-music-api-service-reporting-and-manifest-file) for details.

Comment: Thanks this worked.  
an endpoint like this.
https://7f13b0.ngrok.io/flight/v1.0/radioz
triggered calls like this
https://7f13b0.ngrok.io/flight/v1.0/radiox/prad:32/version

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning an array of `mediaMetadata` objects for the `getMetadataResponse`, with `itemType` of `program`. See https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/286

Comment: Thanks for the help.   I think I'm still missing something,  when I select play now for the program items  I just get an alert.   "Unable to play the selected item"  I'm not seeing any calls to the  cloud queue endpoint.  When the manifest is disabled  it will make calls to the smapi server.   

I've added the new response to the original question.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what the problem might be. Have you tried wiresharking the player to see if you can see traffic between it and the manifest radio endpoint? You won't be able to see content, since it's encrypted, but you'll at least be able to confirm that it's talking.

Comment: Also, did you avoid the capability flags noted in the that docs page about halfway down in the grey box?

Comment: I'm using a proxy so I can view the request/response traffic.  And I've tried it with all capabilities disabled except (support manifest file).    I don't see any traffic when it says "Unable to play selected item".   But if I play some tracks that are configured to play via the smapi sample server.   I do see some calls the reporting endpoint.    POST /flight/radio/timePlayed

Comment: I notice you've got `/radio` for both the radio and reporting endpoints. That could be a problem if that's the case.

Comment: I tried changing the endpoints to something unique,  it didn't have any effect.  Still see the same behavior.   If I change the type from radio to anything else.  The smapi server is called.  As far as I can tell there is something missing from either the manifest or the smapi response.   An  example of the manifest and Soap response  would  be nice to have for reference.    Hardware wise,  I'm testing using a Sonos One (gen1),  running version 10.1.2

Comment: I just want to confirm that you've built, for instance, `/context` and `/itemWindow` endpoints. So `/radio/context` and `/radio/itemWindow`.

Comment: Yes,  those endpoints are reachable.   I added an image to the end of the question with the traffic I can see to the server.