# Sonos Music API service reporting and manifest file

Tags: sonos

We've built a SMAPI implementation that is serving up audiobooks. We're able to browse books and play them, but we're running into problems getting reporting to work correctly. We saw that the reporting endpoints for SMAPI have been [deprecated](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/sonos-music-api/reportplayseconds/), so we're attempting to follow the directions from the ["Add reporting" page](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-reporting/).

We added a reporting path at `https://<our_service>/v1/reporting` and added endpoints for requests to `/context` and `/timePlayed` off of that base path. We're able to hit them directly ourselves, so they're running.

We also created and hosted a manifest file at `https://<our_service>/v1/files/manifest.json`, which we're also able to hit directly and get the JSON file.

```
{
  "schemaVersion": "1.0",
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "type": "reporting",
      "uri": "https://<our_service>/v1/reporting"
    }
  ],
  "strings": {
    "uri": "https://<our_service>/v1/files/strings.xml",
    "version": 1
  }
}
```

After that we added our service for testing using the [customsd page](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/134). We're still able to navigate the menus and play audiobooks, but Sonos appears to be sending the deprecated reporting requests to our SOAP service instead of the new reporting endpoints.

[image: customsd]
[image: customsd]

We found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985381/how-to-trigger-cloud-queue-from-smapi-server) where someone appeared to be using a SMAPI implementation along with the new endpoints, but we haven't been able to figure out what we're doing differently that's causing the problem. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have unsupported version numbers for the reporting endpoint and the Manifest Uri. `v1` is not supported. Acceptable version numbers are `v1.0`, `v2.0` or later. For reference, see:

- The example under **Add a manifest file with an endpoint** in [Add reporting](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-reporting/).
- [POST /timePlayed](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/cloud-queue-api/post-timeplayed/) for a list of features for each version.
- **Cloud queue base URL and API version** in [Play audio (cloud queue)](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/) for details about the URL and API version format.

Updated with more details:

- The endpoint doesn’t have to have report at the end, it can be called anything.
- The order doesn’t matter. Both `/v2.1/reporting` and `/stuff/report/v2.3` are valid.
- The reporting endpoint doesn’t have to be HTTPS, it can be insecure HTTP.
- The manifest URL cannot be insecure, it must use HTTPS.

Comment: The `v1` we have listed in the reporting route wasn't meant to be related to Sonos. We simply put it there so we could version our own service. 

But I'm a bit confused by the cloud queue url requirements. The person from the question I linked was able to use reporting with a `/flight/radio` base route for reporting, which includes no version number at all. And the example on the "Add reporting" page ends with a `/report` instead of the version number.

Comment: We tried changing the reporting route to `/reporting/v2.3` to try including the Cloud Queue version and to `/reporting` to try including no version, but Sonos appeared to still be making the deprecated SMAPI requests instead of using the reporting endpoint we specified.

Comment: The version number becomes before `/report`. Can you confirm that your Manifest "reporting" endpoint URI did not work when you specified it as an insecure URL of `http://<our_service>/v2.3/report`?

Comment: We adjusted the reporting URL to `http://<our_service>/v2.3/report`. It didn't do anything, but it looks like Sonos isn't retrieving our manifest file. Does the manifest file also require a special path?

Comment: Just clarified with Engineering:
* The endpoint doesn’t have to have report at the end, it can be called anything.
* The order also doesn’t matter, so both `/v2.1/reporting` and `/stuff/report/v2.3` are valid. 
* The reporting endpoint doesn’t have to be HTTPS, it can be insecure HTTP.
* However, the manifest URL cannot be insecure, it must use HTTPS.
I am waiting for Engineering to respond with tips on how to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @MaxPauly can you email developer-feedback@sonos.com with the Sonos player diagnostic number after it sends a report to the old method? Please include your StackOverflow username as well. See https://support.sonos.com/s/article/141 for details on submitting system diagnostics.